# updating column based off of parent information

Tags: sql-server

I am a beginner at SQL Server and I have a question about how best to do this.

I have a table that looks like this:

ID      Parent     Level
1      NULL        0
2       1          1
3       1          1
4       2          2
5       2          2
6       3          2
7       2          2
8       5          4
9       4          3
10      6          3
11      6          3

As you can see, all the entries have a Parent and a Level and the database is organized in a tree structure. There are some entries where the Level is set incorrectly such as entry ID #8. The Parent of 8 is 5 and ID 5 has a level of 2 so the level of 8 should be 3 and not 4. There are many incorrect Level values in my table and I'm not sure how to fix this. So far I have this:

UPDATE myTable
SET level=level-1
FROM myTable
WHERE ???;

I am not sure how to fill in the WHERE part or whether this is the best way to do this. Any suggestions are gladly appreciated.

Comment: I'm afraid that any advice I would give you would be dangerous since I don't know exactly what it is that you're trying to accomplish.  Perhaps if you gave some indication of what the table was supposed to look like?

Comment: You could use a cursor to handle the update, but it would be messy.  The first thing to do would be to fix the portion that caused this problem initially.

Answer (score 2):

This will show you the rows that have issues.

```
select
  a.id,
  a.level,
  b.level as parentlevel
from
  tablename a
  join tablename b on a.parent = b.id
where
  a.level <> b.level+1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server 2005 or SQL Server 2008, then you can use a recursive CTE (common table expression).  The [books online article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243.aspx) is pretty straight forward, but here's how you can do it with your code.

-- Create temporary table and insert values

CREATE TABLE dbo.ctetest (childid int primary key not null, parentid int null, level int null);

INSERT INTO dbo.ctetest (childid, parentid) SELECT 1, NULL;

INSERT INTO dbo.ctetest (childid, parentid) SELECT 2, 1;

INSERT INTO dbo.ctetest (childid, parentid) SELECT 3, 1;

INSERT INTO dbo.ctetest (childid, parentid) SELECT 4, 2;

INSERT INTO dbo.ctetest (childid, parentid) SELECT 5, 2;

INSERT INTO dbo.ctetest (childid, parentid) SELECT 6, 3;

INSERT INTO dbo.ctetest (childid, parentid) SELECT 7, 2;

INSERT INTO dbo.ctetest (childid, parentid) SELECT 8, 5;

INSERT INTO dbo.ctetest (childid, parentid) SELECT 9, 4;

INSERT INTO dbo.ctetest (childid, parentid) SELECT 10, 6;

INSERT INTO dbo.ctetest (childid, parentid) SELECT 11, 6;

-- Update table with level data from recursive CTE

WITH recursivecte (childid, parentid, level)

AS

```
(SELECT childid
    , parentid
    , 'level' = 0
FROM dbo.ctetest
WHERE parentid IS NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT ct.childid
    , ct.parentid
    , 'level' = rc.level + 1
FROM dbo.ctetest ct
JOIN recursivecte rc
    ON ct.parentid = rc.childid)
```

UPDATE ct

SET level = rc.level

FROM dbo.ctetest ct

JOIN recursivecte rc

```
ON ct.childid = rc.childid;
```

-- Verify results

SELECT *

FROM dbo.ctetest;

Here's the output from the above query:

Child ID   Parent ID   Level

1   NULL    0

2   1   1

3   1   1

4   2   2

5   2   2

6   3   2

7   2   2

8   5   3

9   4   3

10  6   3

11  6   3

Please note I tested the above code using SQL Server 2008.  I'm assuming it will work in SQL Server 2005 since CTE's were introduced in 2005.